# GEE in Colab and trying to find CDL JSON collapsable tree

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, json

I have used the Google Earth Engine (GEE) code editor for a while now but I am attempting to shift over to being able to use GEE in Colab.

In GEE code editor I was used to using the Console on the right hand side of the screen to print things. For example, if you load in NASS CDL layers and simply say print a layer like and it would display a collapsable tree in the console with all the properties of the image, like this:

In GEE code editor:

```
//Select the year out of the years available
var cdl_20xx = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("USDA/NASS/CDL").filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', '2018')).first()).select('cropland');
print(cdl_20xx);
```

Resulting in something like this:

[image: Tree]

But in Colab when I try to do the same thing in Colab it doesn't give me all the information in the string of info it does output and it's difficult to read since it's not formatted in the collapsable tree like in the GEE code editor.

In Colab:

```
# Import the CDL layers
cdl = ee.ImageCollection("USDA/NASS/CDL")
cdl_20xx = ee.Image(cdl.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', '2018')).first()).select('cropland')
print(cdl_20xx)
```

Resulting in something like this:

[image: What?]

Is there anyway in Colab to recreate this type of collapsable tree found in the GEE code editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `print()` function in the code editor will evaluate server-side objects, then print them. That is not the case in Python. To get the same behavior, you have to evaluate the value yourself: `print(cdl_20xx.getInfo())`

> Is there anyway in Colab to recreate this type of collapsable tree
>   found in the GEE code editor?

You can define a function similar to `print()` in the code editor, automatically calling `getInfo()`, and displaying JSON in a collapsible tree. This works in Jupyter Notebook, and hopefully in Colab too:

```
# Adapted from https://gist.github.com/t27/48b3ac73a1479914f9fe9383e5d45325
import uuid
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

import json
import yaml

def ee_print(obj):
    id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    if isinstance(obj, ee.computedobject.ComputedObject):
        obj = obj.getInfo()
    try:
        obj = yaml.load(str(obj), Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
    except:
        pass
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        json_str = json.dumps(obj)   
    elif isinstance(obj, str):
        return display(HTML('<div id="{}" style="height: auto; width:100%;">{}</div>'.format(id, obj)))
    else:
        json_str = str(obj)
    display(HTML('<div id="{}" style="height: auto; width:100%;"></div>'.format(id)))
    display(HTML("""
        <script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script> <!-- Needed in Colab -->
        <script>
            require(["https://rawgit.com/caldwell/renderjson/master/renderjson.js"], function() {
              renderjson.set_show_to_level(1)
              document.getElementById('%s').appendChild(renderjson(%s))
            });
        </script>
    """ % (id, json_str)))
```

Once defined, you can use it like this:

`ee_print(cdl_20xx)`

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks so much for the response and I'm sorry for my delayed response. I tried it in Colab but it doesn't seem to do anything. When I click run it spins but nothing is produced afterwards. Maybe it is something that doesn't work in Colab?

Comment: I updated my answer, loading require.js. It was already present in Jupyter, but needed to explicitly load it in Colab.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to this project but this worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that for some reason this doesn't work in Brave browser but does work in chrome browser.